# Preg_match with fullwidth numbers

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, cjk

I'm trying to do some validation exercises and I was wondering this code seems to return false always.

```
if (preg_match("/^[０-９]{7}$/", '１２３４５６７')) {
    die('match');
}
```

I'm currently testing for full-width japanese characters/numbers. I'm wondering why it doesn't execute the die command. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing closing parenthesis`. Remove `(`, use `"/^[０-９]{7}$/"`

Comment: I typed the question wrong, fixed it.

Comment: Now, you just need to add `u` modifier. See https://3v4l.org/fGtsQ

Answer (score -1):

**Regex Match for `１２３４５６７`** :

Example Code :

```
<?php
preg_match('/[１２３４５６７]+$/','１２３４５６７',$output);
preg_match('/[１-７]+$/','５１２３４６７',$output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

OR :

```
<?php
preg_match('/[１２３４５６７]{21}$/','１２３４５６７',$output);
preg_match('/[１-７]{21}$/','５１２３４６７',$output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

Related Links :

- http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php
- [PHP Regex to accept only specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356904/php-regex-to-accept-only-specific-characters)
- [PHP preg_replace with UTF-8 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451231/php-preg-replace-with-utf-8-not-working)
- [preg_match and UTF-8 in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725227/preg-match-and-utf-8-in-php)
- [Need regex for utf8 multilingual search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517313/need-regex-for-utf8-multilingual-search-query)
- [PHP preg_func/u or mb_ereg_func for UTF8? (regular expressions with multi-byte-PCRE or multi-byte-POSIX?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056926/php-preg-func-u-or-mb-ereg-func-for-utf8-regular-expressions-with-multi-byte-p)